# What does the number of ways of a processor mean

Tags: hardware, cpu

I am doing some hardware work and I do not know what is the difference between a 4 way processor and an 8 way processor. Can please anyone clarify what does way mean?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of CPU cores.

Answer (score -1):

NOT true!!! 8 way processing is actually 4 cores... called quad core and 4 way processing is actually a dual core processor